# Should one side of an LED monitor get warm?

Tags: display, led

I have recently purchased a new  [LG 22EA53 IPS LED Monitor](http://www.lg.com/levant_en/monitors/lg-22EA53).

Only one side(right side) of this LED monitor gets warm after 1-2 hours of usage, while rest of the three sides do not get warm at all.

Is it normal?

I would also like to know that after how many hours of usage does an average LED monitor starts getting warm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that depends on the monitor type and the usage of the monitor.

One side getting warm means that on that side the engineers placed its major components such as LCD display controllers and other integrated circuits. Usually a monitor getting warm up to 70C is normal.

If you think the heat is unusual, then do not cover it up with cloths or any covers to protect it.

Check the vent area and ensure there is air flow.

Comment: You said 'LCD Display Controllers', do those exist in an LED as well? did you click on this link- http://www.lg.com/levant_en/monitors/lg-22EA53 , cuz I think that should give some idea about the "Monitor type" .

Comment: Well, you LED Display it self a "Liquid Crystal Display" It has crystals in between two layers of the glass. but why the calling it LED? because it's backlid is filled up with LED. old type LCD is filled up with florescent bulb.

Comment: thanks for your information. I believe, right side of the back of LED is not getting warmer than 70c, so is it OK? or should I bother, getting it replaced?

Comment: just talk to the vendor, or claim warrenty